# How to get Stremio app scaling adjusted for a 4k monitor?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, scaling

I am using stremio on Ubuntu (22.04) as the app of choice to watch tv series on my 4k tv. However the search bar is really small. I looked over the internet for some ideas how to fix it, so I came up with the following site with what seems to be the perfect solution:

https://github.com/Stremio/stremio-shell/issues/151

However, I couldn't solve the issue as the author didn't leave many details. I tried to find the stremio desktop file (which I don't know what that is). I found smartcode-stremio.desktop file on my /usr/share/application folder. But adding the described line QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 and save  it didn't do anything at all. Can anyone help me?